# Create list of tuples from empty dict

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I would like to create a dict where the value is a list of tuples

The code below produces a dict with lists of numbers, not list of tuples

```
mydict = {}
for line in file:
  # read a
  # read b
  # read c 
  mydict[a] = (b, c) if a not in mydict else mydict[a].append((b, c))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mydict = defaultdict(list)
for line in file:
    a,b,c = line.split() # or something else
    mydict[a].append((b,c))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) when using normal `dict`'s

```
mydict = {}
mydict.setdefault(a, list()).append((b,c))
```